# Unable to import TokenObtainPairView,TokenRefreshView from JWT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I want to use Json Web token authentication.

but when I import, it gives me error of no reference of TokenObtainPairView,
     TokenRefreshView, found, however I installed jwt.

urls.py:

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path
   from rest_framework_jwt.views import (
     TokenObtainPairView,
     TokenRefreshView,
   )
    from django.conf.urls import url,include

   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), 
       name='token_obtain_pair'),
       path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), 
       name='token_refresh'),
       url(r'^auth/', include('authsystem.urls'))
```

Settings.py:

```
        REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
```

}

when I do pip freeze I have the packages:

```
           Django==2.2.4
           django-cors-headers==3.1.0
           djangorestframework==3.10.2
           djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
           djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.3.0
           Pillow==6.1.0
           PyJWT==1.7.1
           pytz==2019.2
           sqlparse==0.3.0
```

I have tried to import from different way but still it giving me cannot find reference.

Comment: At first sight, there is indeed no such view, you can use `ObtainJSONWebToken`, etc.: https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/views.py

Answer (score 3):

You imported it from the wrong framework, you need to import it from the `rest_framework_simplejwt.views` module, not the <s>`rest_framework_jwt.views`</s> module:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)
```

Is there a specific reason why you installed both `djangorestframework-jwt` and `djangorestframework-simplejwt`?